# How to create a reusable class in LWCs with reusable navigationmixin functions?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, lightning-experience, navigationmixin.navigate

I have a lot of LWCs that require navigation on events. I wanted to simplify the code by having a common utility that can drive the navigation for all the LWCs in the org. I already have a utility based using Javascript classes based on [this](https://github.com/aidan-harding/lwc-classes).

```
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import LightningAlert from 'lightning/alert';

export class NavUtility {
    parent;
    startingPage = 1;
    finalPage;


    constructor(parent, startingPage, finalPage) {
        console.log('Constructor called')
        this.parent = parent;
        this.finalPage = finalPage;
        this.startingPage = startingPage;
    }

    /**
     * Navigates to a standard named page
     * @param {String} pageType pageType for NavigationMixin
     * @param {String} pageName Page name to navigate to
     */
    navigateToPage(pageType, pageName) {
        this.parent[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: pageType,
            attributes: {
                name: pageName
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I use this from one of my LWCs in an experience as

```
   navUtilities = new NavUtility(this, STARTING_PAGE, FINAL_PAGE);

    async actionCancelButton(event) {
      this.formUtilities.navigateToPage('comm__namedPage', 'Home');
}
```

When clicking on the cancel button, I run into an error

```
{
    "component": "markup://force:pageLibrary",
    "componentStack": "[siteforce:navigationProvider]",
    "action": null,
    "name": "TypeError",
    "message": "Error in $A.getCallback() [The type of either or both page reference are invalid ]"
}
```

What is set up incorrectly here ? I've tried using 'this' with querySelector in the utility and it works fine. But with NavigationMixin it fails.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem was because due to an attempt at overload. The function was also overloaded with another set of parameters even though Javascript doesn't support overloading like Java does. Due to this, incorrect function was running and caused this problem.

Obvious fix was to remove the additional function.